# pagination with nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, pagination

I'm searching best usage pattern in nhibernate pagination primary for asp mvc apps. Also, worth to mention is that queries should not use futures bacause there are not supported on all databases.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use linq (`session.Query`) with `Skip` and `Take`. This should work with most providers and it's probably the simplest way to implement it.

For example, to take 3rd page of length 10, you'd call:

```
 var pageEntities = session.Query<YourEntityType>().Skip( 20 ).Take( 10 );
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that `QueryOver` works exactly in the same way.